# How to create a word before function in a Laravel Model

Tags: php, laravel, function, model

I have a list of countries in my database.

I want to add the word "**THE**" before certain countries when needed.

- **Example:** **The** Dominican Republic.

How can I correct this to return the correct result? At the moment it is only returning the ELSE portion.

---

This is in my Model: (`$this->name` returns the country names.)

```
    public function getTheCountryNameAttribute(){
        $the_country_name = [
                'Dominican Republic', 'Bahamas'
        ];
        if($this->name == $the_country_name) {
            return 'the' . ' ' . $this->name;
        }else{
            return $this->name;
        }
    }
```

---

Output to view like this:

```
<h3>{{ $country->theCountryName }}</h3>
```

---

If there is a better way with a Laravel helper I would love to see that option as well.

Comment: better way of what? you are trying to compare a string to an entire array ... PHP has functions for dealing with arrays

Comment: instead of using `$this->name == $the_country_name`, you could use `in_array($this->name, $the_country_name)` to check if `name` is matched with any item in array `the_country_name ` or not

Comment: here https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php  the function you want is in that list ... you are saying you need something that "Checks if a value exists in an array"?

Comment: @ThienHuynh Thank you, That is what I was needing. Really appreciate the help. Pop that in an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: I think you need to use laravel in_array() method to check for $the_country_name array exists inside the  country names table if exists return the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `$this->name == $the_country_name`, you could use `in_array($this->name, $the_country_name)` to check if name is matched with any item in array `the_country_name` or not.

Hope it would help